# Efficiently finding the low median over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, vectorization

I am very new to Python, so I assume this is probably a basic question. I found a few solutions online but could not find the exact thing I was looking for. Currently I am searching for a way to find the "low median" over 3 columns of data. If only 2 values of the 3 columns are populated then I would like to take the lower value.

Here is what I have found so far

```
df['median']=np.nanmedian(df[['val1','val2','val3']], axis=1)
```

The above was not a workable solution as I did not see any information on an argument to take the low median when there are an even number of values. Additionally I found that there is a function that does what I am looking for

```
statistics.median_low()
```

However, I am unsure how to apply it over multiple columns without using some sort of function that calculates each median row-wise one at a time (ie. a loop or apply function). Ideally, I would like a vectorized solution using this function which will calculate the medians simultaneously. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: If its three columns (odd number), why would you need to worry about low?

Comment: Sometimes there are NULL values

Comment: By NULL, you mean NaNs, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few optimizations are possible for three columnar data making use of sorting each row and then simply choosing the first or the second column based on the `NaNs`, which on account of being sorted would be pushed to the end of each row. This lets us use `slicing` thereafter to do the choosing and get the desired `median_low` values for each row.

Here's assembling those into a vectorized solution -

```
a = df.values
a_sorted = np.sort(a,1)
df['median'] = np.where(np.isnan(a_sorted[:,2]), a_sorted[:,0], a_sorted[:,1])
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
# Proposed in this post
def vectorized_app(df):
    a = df.values
    a_sorted = np.sort(a,1)
    df['median'] = np.where(np.isnan(a_sorted[:,2]), a_sorted[:,0], a_sorted[:,1])
    return df

# @piRSquared's new soln
def vectorized_app2(df):
    v = np.sort(df.values, axis=1)
    n = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(v), axis=1)
    j = (n - 1) // 2
    i = np.arange(len(v))
    return df.assign(median_low=v[i, j])

# @piRSquared's old soln
from statistics import median_low
def apply_app(df):
    med = lambda x: median_low(x.dropna())
    return df.apply(med, 1)
```

Timings -

```
In [433]: # Setup input dataframe and set one per row as NaN
     ...: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(10000,3)).astype(float)
     ...: idx = np.random.randint(0,3,a.shape[0])
     ...: a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), idx] = np.nan
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(a)
     ...: df.columns = [['val1','val2','val3']]
     ...: 

In [435]: %timeit vectorized_app(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 481 µs per loop

In [436]: %timeit vectorized_app2(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 892 µs per loop

In [434]: %timeit apply_app(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank you! Will test later today and report back the results.

Comment: I posted a new solution.

Comment: @piRSquared Updated timings.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**
This is a generalized solution that works for any sized array.

I sort each row, count how many non-nulls, then determine where the `median_low` must be.

```
v = np.sort(df.values, axis=1)
n = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(v), axis=1)
j = (n - 1) // 2
i = np.arange(len(v))

df.assign(median_low=v[i, j])

   A    B    C  median_low
0  4  5.0  8.0         5.0
1  3  6.0  4.0         4.0
2  4  9.0  NaN         4.0
3  1  NaN  NaN         1.0
```

---

**Old Answer**

First, you'll want to use `pd.DataFrame.apply` with the `axis=1` option to apply the function to each row.

Second, `median_low` will consider nulls.  You don't want that, so make a lambda to drop nulls then use `median_low`

---

```
import pandas as pd
from statistics import median_low

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [4, 5, 8],
    [3, 6, 4],
    [4, 9],
    [1]
], columns=list('ABC'))

med = lambda x: median_low(x.dropna())

df.apply(med, 1)

0    5.0
1    4.0
2    4.0
3    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, it is pretty clear and makes sense. The only thing is that I need a vectorized solution. It is my understanding that when using apply over rows it functions in a way similar to a loop, calculating one value at a time.

Comment: When I answer these questions.  I usually post the first thing that comes to my head that works.  I then explore to see if I can come up with a better answer.  So far, you have something that works.  We'll see what else I can come up with, or what others can come up with.